# Is there a more concise way to write this simply ruby conditional and loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can the following code be written more neatly and concisely?

```
<% if Post.all.count > 0 %>                                                                                                                                                                              
  <% for post in Post.all do %>
    Display my post
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>No one has posted anything yet.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks mostly ok to me. Just get rid of `for in` loop (in favor of `.each`) :)

Comment: Or may be you can add `@posts = Post.all` in your controller and use the instance variable in views, just to keep presentation logic in view. :)

Comment: let's not access the model from view, clean MVC

Comment: Questions like this should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. See the "[faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site)" for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `#exists` which I think is faster than counting and use `#each` instead of for loops.  I used `#find_each` below so that it fetches by batch of 1000.

```
<% if Post.exists? %>
  <% Post.find_each do |post| %>
    Display my post
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>No one has posted anything yet.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I used Post.all just as a means of getting all the code in one place (I'm using a controller fellas, I promise), but I was more curious about the loops and conditionals.

Answer (score 3):

In the Post Controller

> @posts = Post.find(:all)

In the view page

> `<% @posts.each do |post|%>
>         Display post
>     <%  end  %>`

```
<p><%= "No one has posted anything yet." if @posts.present?  %></p>
```

Please do try this..

Answer (score 0):

The better way to use enumerator [iterator](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) of `for loop` and loading posts (inside controller's action) before use:

```
# PostsController#index
@posts = Post.all  
# instead of Post.all you be able to use different options like:
# filtering, pagination and ordering
@posts = Post.where(:published => true).order("created_at DESC")

# index.html.erb
<% if @posts.present? %>                                                                                                                                                                              
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    Display my post
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>No one has posted anything yet.</p>
<% end %>
```